# Ломается расчет времени

Tags: python, числа

**Моя задача высчитать время из секунд** 
Я написал такой код:

```
def pretty_time(raw):
    if raw % 60 != raw:
        s = raw % 60
        m = raw // 60
        if m % 60 != m:
            h = s // 60
            m %= 60
            s = m % 60
            pretty = f'{h}ч {m}м {s}с'
        else:
            pretty = f'{m}мин, {s} сек'
    else:
        pretty = f'{raw} сек'
    return pretty
```

**На вид все должно работать правильно?** 
Так и есть, но после проверки оказалось что...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(10):
        print(pretty_time(int(input(''))))
```

> 5  
> `5 сек` 
>
> 59 
> `59 сек` 
>
> 60 
> `1мин, 0 сек` 
>
> 700 
> `11мин, 40 сек` 
>
> 7777 
> `0ч 9м 9с` 
>
> 3600 
> `0ч 0м 0с` 
>
> 86400 
> `0ч 0м 0с` 
>
> 1 
> `1 сек` 
>
> 555 
> `9мин, 15 сек` 
>
> 10000 
> `0ч 46м 46с`

**Не понимаю, как так могло выйти?**

Python 3.10rc2

Comment: Вывод нуля секунд как-то слабо соотносится с pretty...

Comment: Вопрос оформлен по правилам ресурса. Приведена собственная попытка решения и тесты. Не понимаю - зачем минусовать и критиковать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу 2 ошибки:

- В коде `h = s // 60` - а надо `h = m // 60`. Часы ведь от минут вычисляются.
- И второй раз `s = m % 60` испортит вам секунды. Эту (второй раз встречающуюся) строку вообще надо выкинуть из кода.

Итого вся функция должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
def pretty_time(raw):
    if raw >= 60:
        s = raw % 60
        m = raw // 60
        if m >= 60:
            h = m // 60
            m %= 60
            pretty = f'{h}ч {m}м {s}с'
        else:
            pretty = f'{m}мин, {s}сек'
    else:
        pretty = f'{raw} сек'
    return pretty
```

Если не нужно выводить элементы времени с нулевыми значениями, то можно вот так:

```
def pretty_time(raw):
    if not raw: return '0 сек'
    time_values = []
    for div,text in ((60, 'сек'), (60, 'мин'), (24, 'ч'), (raw, 'д')):
        v = raw % div
        if v: time_values.append(f'{v} {text}')
        raw //= div
    return ' '.join(time_values[::-1])
```

Comment: спасибо, 1 вариант работает правильно. расскажите как адаптировать под дни а то и недели, буду очень благодарен за хороший ответ. ну а 2 мне не нужен, время всегда ровное)

Comment: @somebodycalledleestarb Вот второй вариант уже поддерживает дни. Можно и недели туда добавить просто заменив цикл на `for div,text in ((60, 'сек'), (60, 'мин'), (24, 'ч'), (7, 'д'), (raw, 'нед')): `.

Comment: благодарю за скорость, кстати интересно что если ввести отрицательное число мы получим время оставшееся до 48 часов<br>а так все прекрасно, спасибо за работу!

Answer (score 2):

Вообще в таких вычислениях лучше не считать сущности отдельно, а попытаться как-то универсально их обрабатывать, тогда заведомо меньше ошибок будет в коде. Например, если обрабатывается время не больше, чем сутки, то можно использовать такой код, поскольку часы, минуты и секунды вычисляются по совершенно одинаковому алгоритму - выводим остаток от деления, потом делим нацело и т.д.:

```
def pretty_time(raw):
    res = ''
    for t in 'смч':
        res = f'{raw % 60}{t} {res}'
        raw //= 60
        if raw == 0:
            break
    print(res)

pretty_time(59)
pretty_time(555)
pretty_time(10000)
```

Вывод:

```
59с 
9м 15с 
2ч 46м 40с
```

Но и для бОльших количеств времени можно использовать похожий алгорим, только нужно будет перебирать не только единицы времени, но и одновременно величину делителя для получения этих единиц. Алгоритм чуть усложнится, но останется таким же универсальным.

Comment: благодарю, а не расскажите как со днями адаптировать (почему бы и не с неделями)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в алгоритме, конечно же!

```
def pretty_time(raw):
    if raw % 60 != raw:
        s = raw % 60 # s всегда меньше 60!!!
        m = raw // 60
        if m % 60 != m:
            h = s // 60 # если число меньше 60 разделить на 60, то целая часть всегда будет 0
```

Т.е. мало того, что количество часов вычисляется не из общего количества секунд, а из того количества секунд, которое не уместилось в целую минуту, так еще и само это вычисление происходит неправильно.